# Numeric overflow in a query

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

As part of a SQL query I have the following

```
iif(rapport_nc, 35, 0) AS rapport
```

If the first record returns a 0 (and that's the case), I get a numeric overflow error on every record that returns 35.

How can I get around this without "massaging" the data?

Answer (score 4):

It's a good practice to wrap expressions that have a variable return length with CAST().  For example:

```
CAST(IIF(rapport_nc, 35, 0) AS I)
```

Answer (score 2):

Bernard (and others new to VFP).  VFP queries actually run the query twice, once for the first record just to confirm the final column types and sizes, then for the actual query of ALL records.  So, as your IIF(), if the first record of your table was a result of 0, then it sets the final column size to 1 digit and thus failing.  So, your solution of IIF( condition, 35, 00 ) will now recognize both possible answers as 2 digits.  This will ALSO happen if you trim strings, such as trimming names, address or similar and typically resolved with PADR( somefield, finalLengthWanted ).

Answer (score 0):

I thought of trying  "IIF(rapport_nc,35,00) AS rapport" and it worked. Sorry for the trouble. /b